# How to randomly select a passage of text from a text file

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app which deals with a text file. Basically I am starting off trying to read text from a text file and display it within my text view but the text doesn't appear. I thought however I may as well mention what I am trying to implement as the final version.

Basically in my `assets/files` folder I have a text file named `jokes.txt`

The text file contains 3 jokes as displayed below:

```
Teacher: "Kids, what does the chicken give you?"
Student: "Meat!"
Teacher: "Very good! Now what does the pig give you?"
Student: "Bacon!"
Teacher: "Great! And what does the fat cow give you?"
Student: "Homework!"


My friend thinks he is smart. He told me an onion is the only food that makes you cry, so I threw a coconut at his face.


A child asked his father, "How were people born?" So his father said, "Adam and Eve made babies, then their babies became adults and made babies, and so on." The child then went to his mother, asked her the same question and she told him, "We were monkeys then we evolved to become like we are now." The child ran back to his father and said, "You lied to me!" His father replied, "No, your mom was talking about her side of the family."
```

What I want to do is that when the `Content` page is loaded, it will randomly display any one of those jokes within the text view `content_text`.

The user reads the joke and if they select the button `selectAnotherButton` then it randomly select a joke from the same text file and display it on screen, replacing the previous joke.

How can this be implemented? Below I am trying to do a basic read from the file and then set the text in textview?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);

    Button backButton = findViewById(R.id.button_back);
    Button selectAnotherButton = findViewById(R.id.button_select_another);

    TextView contentText = findViewById(R.id.content_text);

    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            backToMainActivity();
        }
    });

    try {
        // file to inputstream
        InputStream input = getAssets().open("jokes.txt");
        // myData.txt can't be more than 2 gigs.
        int size = input.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        input.read(buffer);
        input.close();
        // byte buffer into a string
        String text = new String(buffer);
        contentText.setText(text);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: you need a delimiter to know where each joke starts and ends, could be those 2 empty lines

Comment: @jhamon I'll probably place --- as my delimeter in the text file

Answer (score 0):

> I advise you to divide your code into functions:

```
public static String[] readAllFileIntoArray(String filename) {
    return FileUtils.readLines(new File(filename), "utf-8");
}

public static String randomChoice(String[] array) {
    java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();
    int index = random.nextInt(array.length);
    return array[index];
}

public static String fileRandomChoice(String filename) {
    String[] file_lines = readAllFileIntoArray(filename);
    return randomChoice(file_lines);
}
```

Comment: he doesn't want a random line, but a random set of delimited lines

Comment: [how to recognize a help vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)

Answer (score 0):

for the part on how to select random jokes and displaying them I can suggest the following :

- In your text file separate every joke with a symbol (for example this one #).
- Then read the whole file and check how many separates are in the file (in your example there is three jokes so three separators ).
- And finally you can call the `Random` class to give you a random integer between 1 and 3.
- After knowing the number of the joke you get the position of the chosen separator and  copy the text from a start position until the position of the separator.

Comment: I'll have to be shown how to implement this in code, have tried for the last 2 hours but not getting anywhere with it.